# Automated Syslog Error Solution Finder

Tags: monitoring, automation, syslog, resolution

Any automated syslog solution finding frameworks?  I want my central syslog server to email a list of problems, **their severity and suggested solutions**.
There have been several questions about centralising system logs and alternative log analysis systems, but I don't get the impression that any of them help with issue resolution.

**A little background:** 
At work I am now literally doing the work of two people, and both jobs have expanded beyond their initial frameworks.  It is not so bad as I have helpers, but they are little more than smart monkeys.  While one of my predecessors [I have two, that is how I know I have the jobs of two people] set-up logwatch to email its results out, my monkeys don't have the skills necessary to identify unimportant data.  This has caused all of them, and myself sadly, to setup email filters and ignore the whole thing until something goes "bang".
It would be handy to have someone else tell them what is important, what is connected, and to suggest a few ways to resolve the issue (I could train then to research the solution first, *ha!*).
My reading of the Splunk and Octopussy sites indicates that I still need to bring my own highly trained monkey to the party.  Which I am several years from having.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write the solution (or better link to the solution that you wrote on your wiki) in the mail sent by [Octopussy](http://www.octopussy.pm) or [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are hinting at is what I call "Predictive Analytics" - it is essentially, "how do I know what I don't know?" Which is kind of a tough question to answer as you are no doubt aware.
I am the creator of [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.pro) (syslog analysis tool) and have been working on another tool for quite some time now (years) that attempts to add this type of artificial intelligence to unknown messages and have recently put up a "proof of concept". It's still in alpha so I don't want to provide the link publicly, but would be happy to share it with you if you want to send me a private message.
Once completed, I plan to integrate it into LogZilla so that people can have their own built-in monkeys :-)